# Can't add class through .attr method

Tags: d3.js, svg

I'm just adding this to a simple svg element

```
const svg = d3.select('body')
  .append('svg')
  .attr('width', '960px')
  .attr('height', '500px');

svg
  .append('rect')
  .attr({
    rx    : 6,
    ry    : 6,
    x     : 50,
    y     : 50,
    width : 100,
    height: 0,
    class : 'selection'
  });
```

the final dom looks like the following

[image]

Why any attribute does not appears?

I'm really new with d3. I'm using d3 4.6.0

Comment: What version of d3 are you using? Also what is the 50, 50 supposed to do?

Comment: You can't set attributes with an object literal in d3 v4, you have to download a plugin called d3-selection-multi